# What's the name of this problem? (Search for minimal satisfying sets)

Tags: algorithms, terminology, search-problem

**NB:**  I've been trying to Google for prior work on the problem described later in this post, but the search results I get for all the keywords I can come up with (e.g. `minimal satisfying sets`) are inundated with false positives.  In this post I'm just asking for *terminology/nomenclature/buzzwords* to make my Google searches more specific.

---

First, some assumptions and definitions.

We restrict our attention to subsets of some finite set $U$.  (IOW, below, a "set" is shorthand for a "subset of $U$".)

Let $p$ be a predicate on sets such that

$$(p(A) \land (A \subseteq B)) \Longrightarrow p(B).$$

Let's say that a set $A$ is *satisfying* iff $p(A)$.  If $A$ is satisfying, and no proper subset of $A$ is satisfying, then we'll say that $A$ is a *minimal* satisfying set.

---

The problem is:

> Find all the minimal satisfying sets.

More specifically, I'm looking for algorithms to find all minimal satisfying sets optimally (or at least efficiently).

---

I should mention a variant of this problem that I'm particularly interested in, just in case it goes by a different name.  This variant is the special case of the above where $p(U)$ holds.  IOW, we know that there is at least one satisfying set.

Comment: First, [Sperner's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem) implies that there could be more than polynomially many minimal satisfying sets, so that rules out a poly-time algorithm.  (Summary of the counterexample: $p(A)$ holds for exactly those sets containing $|U|/2$ elements.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: by assumption, if $p(A)$, then $p(B)$ for every superset of $A$, so your counterexample cannot arise given the problem statement.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that $p(A)$ holds for sets containing at least $|U|/2$ elements; this leaves the superpolynomial number of sets having exactly $|U|/2$ elements as the *minimal* satisfying sets.  (No set containing exactly |U|/2 elements can be a superset of any other such set, since they have the same number of elements.)

Comment: I suggest `learning monotone boolean functions`, and if you don't want stochastic algorithms used mainly in learning theory, you can add the key word `deterministic`.